# How to validate a user's birth date in JavaScript with a Regular Expression?

Tags: javascript, html

How to validate a user's birth date with a Regular Expression in JavaScript? Is `test` a preferred method for validating user input with a Regular Expression?

```js
function myValidator() {
  result = true;
  
  var today = new Date();
  var todayYear = today.getFullYear();

  var userBirthDate = new Date(document.getElementById("dob").value);

  var regexVar = new RegExp("([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{4})");
  var regexVarTest = regexVar.test(userBirthDate);

  var cutOff19 = todayYear - 19;
  var cutOff95 = todayYear - 95;

  if (isNaN(userBirthDate)) {
    dobErrMsg.innerHTML = "date of birth must be a number";
  } else if (regexVarTest == false) {
    dobErrMsg.innerHTML = "enter date of birth as dd/mm/yyyy";
  } else if (userBirthDate >= cutOff19) {
    dobErrMsg.innerHTML = "you have to be older than 19";
  } else if (userBirthDate <= cutOff95) {
    dobErrMsg.innerHTML = "you have to be younger than 95";
  }

  return result;

}
```

```html
<p>
  <label for="dob">Date of Birth</label>
  <input type="text" name="dob" id="dob" maxlength="10" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" pattern="([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{4})" required="required" />
  <span id="dobErrMsg"></span>
</p>
<button onclick="myValidator()">Run validation</button>
```

Comment: You initialize `regexVarTest` then you refer to `regularExpressionTest` ...

Comment: That and `birthday` isn't defined anywhere

Comment: That date format is ambiguous. JavaScript engines interpret that format as mm/dd/yyyy. Better use a more reliable method to parse the date

Comment: BTW, the snippet is still producing "birthday is not defined"

Comment: Just use a date input...  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date

Comment: A more reliable way to parse a date is with the YYYY-MM-DD format. You can reuse your regex to get that format as I have indicated in my answer below.

Comment: Note also that `result` is an undefined variable: but a question on Stack Overflow should not be a debug session where you keep updating the question. It is better to debug your code first, (using developer tools available in every major browser), making sure all variables are declared and spelled in the correct way, and then ask the question ;-)

Comment: @thezeroandone No, I meant use a date input and throw away all your validation code.  And, if you need older browser compatibility, use a polyfill instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several issues:

- You pass a Date to the regex `test` method, but you should really pass the input string.
- Several variables are not defined, including `result`, `birthday`, `todayYear`.
- The cutoff points seem to be defined as numbers (number of years), but in the `if` conditions they are treated as dates. This cannot work. You should really subtract a number of years from the current date (resulting in a date). Just comparing calendar years is not a right method to determine someone's age. At the time of writing, someone born in January 2000 is older than 19, while someone born in December 2000 is younger than 19.
- An error message saying that the date is not a number is misleading to the user who had entered "13/13/1990". It should just say the date is invalid.
- The regex should require that the input does not contain other things than just the date -- it should use `^` and `$` anchors
- The dd/mm/yyyy format is ambiguous. When passed to `new Date`, it will be interpreted as mm/dd/yyyy. Better first convert it to some standard format like YYYY-MM-DD. The code below does this conversion of the dd/mm/yyyy input to the YYYY-MM-DD format, before passing it to the `Date` constructor.

Also, since there is nothing dynamic in your regex, you can just use a regex literal, instead of calling the `RegExp` constructor.

Here is the corrected code:

```js
function myValidator() {
  var birthday = document.getElementById("dob").value; // Don't get Date yet...
  var regexVar = /^([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{4})$/; // add anchors; use literal
  var regexVarTest = regexVar.test(birthday); // pass the string, not the Date
  var userBirthDate = new Date(birthday.replace(regexVar, "$3-$2-$1")); // Use YYYY-MM-DD format
  var todayYear = (new Date()).getFullYear(); // Always use FullYear!!
  var cutOff19 = new Date(); // should be a Date
  cutOff19.setFullYear(todayYear - 19); // ...
  var cutOff95 = new Date();
  cutOff95.setFullYear(todayYear - 95);
  if (!regexVarTest) { // Test this before the other tests
    dobErrMsg.innerHTML = "enter date of birth as dd/mm/yyyy";
  } else if (isNaN(userBirthDate)) {
    dobErrMsg.innerHTML = "date of birth is invalid";
  } else if (userBirthDate > cutOff19) {
    dobErrMsg.innerHTML = "you have to be older than 19";
  } else if (userBirthDate < cutOff95) {
    dobErrMsg.innerHTML = "you have to be younger than 95";
  } else {
    dobErrMsg.innerHTML = "";
  }
  return userBirthDate; // Return the date instead of an undefined variable
}
```

```html
<p>
  <label for="dob">Date of Birth</label>
  <input type="text" name="dob" id="dob" maxlength="10" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" pattern="([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{4})" required="required" />
  <span id="dobErrMsg"></span>
</p>
<button onclick="myValidator()">Run validation</button>
```

As to the meaning of "older than 19": if this means that a person should be 20 years or older (and not just 19 plus one day), than don't subtract 19, but subtract 20.

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues in your code as explained in the comments for missing initialization of some variables.

However the issue with regex is, when you do

```js
new Date("07/03/2010");
```

it results to

```
Sat Jul 03 2010 00:00:00 GMT+0530
```

This is why your regex which should pass a value such as 07/03/2010 is not passing the change value. You need to run the regex on the direct value of

```js
document.getElementById("dob").value
```

So it should be something like

```js
var userBirthDate = document.getElementById("dob").value;
var regexVar = new RegExp("([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{4})");
var regexVarTest = regexVar.test(userBirthDate);
```

```js
function myValidator() {
  var userBirthDate = document.getElementById("dob").value;
  var regexVar = new RegExp("([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{4})");
  var regexVarTest = regexVar.test(userBirthDate);
  
  alert(regexVarTest);
}
```

```html
<p>
  <label for="dob">Date of Birth</label>
  <input type="text" name="dob" id="dob" maxlength="10" required 
         placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" 
         pattern="([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{4})"/>
  <span id="dobErrMsg"></span>
</p>
<button onclick="myValidator()">Run validation</button>
```

Comment: @thezeroandone Another option could be to just use [`<input type="date">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date)

Comment: @thezeroandone I have used alert just to show that the regex pass the value provided by you in the input box . you will have to keep you logic of displaying the error messages as per your requirement.

Answer (score -1):

```js
function myValidator() {
      var result = true;
      var birthday = document.getElementById("dob").value
      var regexVar = new RegExp("(([012]{1})?[0-9]{1}|[3]?[01]{1})\/(([0]{1})?[0-9]{1}|[1]{1}?[012]{1})\/([12]{1}[09]{1}[0-9]{2})");
      var regexVarTest = regexVar.test(birthday);
      //if format is valid
      if (regexVarTest){
        var date_array = birthday.split('/')
        var userBirthDate = new Date(date_array[2], parseInt(date_array[1])-1, date_array[0]);
        var userage = userBirthDate.getFullYear();
        var todayYear = new Date().getFullYear()
        var cutOff19 = todayYear - 19;
        var cutOff95 = todayYear - 95;
      }
      
      dobErrMsg.innerHTML = "";
      
      if (regexVarTest == false) {
        dobErrMsg.innerHTML = "enter date of birth as dd/mm/yyyy";
        result = false;
      } else if (isNaN(Date.parse(date_array[2]+'-'+date_array[1]+'-'+date_array[0])) || new Date(date_array[2]+'-'+date_array[1]+'-'+date_array[0]).getDate() != parseInt(date_array[0])){
        dobErrMsg.innerHTML = "enter valid date";
        result = false;
      } else if (userage >= cutOff19) {
        dobErrMsg.innerHTML = "you have to be older than 19";
        result = false;
      } else if (userage <= cutOff95) {
        dobErrMsg.innerHTML = "you have to be younger than 95";
        result = false;
      }
    
      return result;
    
    }
```

```html
<p>
  <label for="dob">Date of Birth</label>
  <input type="text" name="dob" id="dob" maxlength="10" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" pattern="([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{4})" required="required" />
  <span id="dobErrMsg"></span>
</p>
<button onclick="myValidator()">Run validation</button>
```

I think you are looking for this. Let me know if that solve your problem.

Update: I have update date validation which was missing till now.

Comment: @thezeroandone some date validation have added and regex changed to support date validation.