# How to validate a date in a particular format in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dialogflow-es

I am using Dialogflow to pass the dateofbirth and convert it into specific format using a particular function written in helperfile in webhook end .

For this,I  need to validate whether dateofbirth in in correct format before converting it  inside helper file.

dateofbirth format to be validated:
mm/dd/yyyy and 20 August,1989 (dd Month,Year)

Only if the dateofbirth are in the above mentioned format,It can go inside function.

The code is given below:

```
const formatdob =   (df,globalParameter,dob) => {   
    try {                        
        let dob = df._request.queryResult.queryText //taking input from user
        globalParameter["dob"]=dob; //assigning it to Dialogflow parameters
        if(dob.length!=0 ){         //need to validate whether dob is in above mentioned format
            const d = new Date(dob);   
            return new Date(
                Date.UTC(
                  d.getFullYear(),
                  d.getMonth(),
                  d.getDate(),
                  d.getHours(),
                  d.getMinutes(),
                  d.getSeconds()
                )                 
              ).toISOString();                              
        }                                    
        
        console.log("else block");
        return dob;
    }                  
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        throw err;
    }   
};

module.exports = formatdob;
```

I tried using regex but its getting too complicated.Could you please help me out with this?

Comment: Use `Intl` (which is built-in to JavaScript now) or `Moment.js`. You should not attempt to handle date processing yourself because it's fraught with hundreds of edge-cases that will trip you up: https://gist.github.com/timvisee/fcda9bbdff88d45cc9061606b4b923ca

Comment: do not use regex

Comment: Also, you should probably use TypeScript - as your code is making assumptions about data-types without verifying them as well as inconsistently (and incorrectly) validating input...

Comment: Finally, your `throw err` line will reset the stack-trace of any thrown exception. Instead, only re-throw errors by throwing a _new_ wrapper or container around them (and ensure you only ever throw `Error` or a subtype of `Error`).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to validate a user's birth date in JavaScript with a Regular Expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55851164/how-to-validate-a-users-birth-date-in-javascript-with-a-regular-expression)

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you have to accept _only_ `mm/dd/yyyy`? Why not respect the user's own culture/locale settings by using `<input type="date" />` and simply have them do a click-through confirmation of the date (by formatting it using the user's own culture settings but using the full month name instead of a number)?

Comment: @Dai as your suggestion helped OP, could you provide an answer with more details? It might help other members with similar issue.

Comment: @PjoterS I have posted the answer using Moment.js..Hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

I used Moment.js for the above question as suggested in the comment section.

```
const moment=require("moment");
/**
 * Webhook integration with bigquery to fetch user details
 * @param {object} 
 */

const formatdob =   (df,globalParameter,dob) => {   //birthDate should be in mm/dd/yyyy format
    try {
             
        console.log("globalParameter",globalParameter);
        if(dob===""){
        let dob = df._request.queryResult.queryText
        globalParameter["dob"]=dob;       
        if(moment(dob, "MMMM DD,YYYY").isValid() || moment(dob, "MM/DD/YYYY").isValid()){
            const d = new Date(dob);
            return new Date(
                Date.UTC(
                  d.getFullYear(),
                  d.getMonth(),
                  d.getDate(),
                  d.getHours(),
                  d.getMinutes(),
                  d.getSeconds()
                )
              ).toISOString();
            }
            return dob;
            }
            console.log("else block");
            return dob;
        }
            
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        throw err;
    }


};

module.exports = formatdob;
```